# How can I make the model field to be autoincremented in sql server 2017 starting value 1990 and increment By 1 using stored prodcedure

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertBMW] 

        (@Make varchar(50)  
        ,@Model int out 
        ,@Location varchar(50)  
        ,@Km int, @Color varchar(50)    
        ,@Location varchar(50)  
        ,@Value int )
 AS 
BEGIN   
INSERT INTO [dbo].[VehicleInfo] Make,Model,Km,Color,Location,Value  
VALUES(@Make,@Model,@Location,@Km,@Color,@Location,@Value
```

Comment: What are you asking here exactly? You posted some SAL but there's no context, and no expected results/behaviour. Can you please expand on your quesion (by editting it).

Comment: Can you add your table definition please

Comment: Possibly this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/14db45ce-4313-49bd-a4e7-cd2b0713efa6/autoincrement-column-using-stored-procedure-?forum=transactsql

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table]
(
 [VehicleID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Make] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [Model] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [Km] INT NOT NULL, 
    [Color] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [Location] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [Value] INT NOT NULL
)

Comment: What are the current values in 'Model' field?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified whether the Model column has been defined as an identity column, but assuming it has you can use DBCC CHECKIDENT to change the seed value for the identity column on this table, in your case:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.VehicleInfo', SEED, 1989)
```

And subsequent inserts will then use id values starting from 1990.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> The seed value is the value inserted into an identity column for the very first row loaded into the table. All subsequent rows contain the current identity value **plus** the increment value where current identity value is the last identity value generated for the table or view.

Comment: I'm new to SQL server. The model is not a primary key.Please help.

Comment: An identity is not the same thing as a primary key. Although they are often used together, a column can be defined as an identity column without being a primary key

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you may try with the following solution.
Your `model` column is `varchar(50)` and I guess, that the values in this column are numbers. So you need to read the max value from this column 
and make additional calculations.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertBMW] (
    @Make varchar(50),
    @Model int OUTPUT,
    @Location varchar(50),
    @Km int, 
    @Color varchar(50),
    @Location varchar(50),
    @Value int
)
AS 
BEGIN
    -- Get current Model value
    SELECT @Model = ISNULL(MAX(CONVERT(int, Model), 0)
    FROM [dbo].[VehicleInfo]

    -- Set new Model value
    IF @Model < 1990 SET @Model = 1990
    ELSE SET @Model = @Model + 1

    -- Insert values
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[VehicleInfo] 
        (Make, Model, Km, Color, Location, Value)  
    VALUES 
        (@Make, @Model, @Location, @Km, @Color, @Location, @Value)
END
```